# DevDemon Forms Field Settings popup doesn't show up in correct location when field is in a column

Tags: forms, jquery, devdemon-forms

I am using EE 2.11.2 and Forms 3.5.3

In the form builder tool, when you click the gear icon to edit the field settings, the Field Settings popup shows up. It is supposed to appear right where that element is in the form. This works for most form elements, but it doesn't work properly for form elements within a multi-column layout. The popup shows up at the very top of the form, which means you have to scroll all the way up there to edit the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I added a line after 379 of form_builder.js, so

```
var Parent = $(e.target).parents('div.FormElem').last();
```

becomes

```
var Parent = $(e.target).parents('div.FormElem').last();
var Parent_Scroll = $(e.target).parents('div.FormElem').last();
```

I added Parent_Scroll as the element that determines the position that the Settings modal should scroll down to. Then I had to update what is now lines 393 and 394 from

```
var TopBefore = Settings[0].offsetTop+Parent[0].offsetTop+Settings.height();
var TopAfter = Settings[0].offsetTop-Parent[0].offsetTop;
```

to

```
var TopBefore = Settings[0].offsetTop+Parent_Scroll[0].offsetTop+Settings.height();
var TopAfter = Settings[0].offsetTop-Parent_Scroll[0].offsetTop;
```

and now the Field Settings popup shows up where it should!